# Bash color output fails

Tags: bash, sed, quoting

Is it sed or echo problem? What I'm doing wrong?

```
$> cat ~/bin/color_test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

ColorOff='\e[0m'       # Text Reset
BWhite='\e[1;37m'      # Bold White

string="test TEST test"
echo -e "$string" | sed -e "s/TEST/${BWhite}TEST${ColorOff}/g"

$> ~/bin/color_test.sh 
test e[1;37mTESTe[0m test
```

TEST with bold highlighting is what was expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sed` doesn't treat `\e` as an escape sequence. With GNU sed, and most other sed implementations out there, `\e` in an `s` replacement text just means `e`. The only backslash escapes you can use portably in `s` replacement text are `\\` to mean a backslash, `\&` to mean a literal `&`, `\/` (where `/` is the delimiter character) for a literal `/`, and `\1` through `\9` for backreferences. GNU sed and BusyBox (but not e.g. OpenBSD sed) adds `\n` for a newline. Thus the output of your sed command has a literal `e`.

In bash, you can easily put a literal escape character in your variables from the start. `\e` is one of the escape sequences recognized by the `$'…'` construct.

```
ColorOff=$'\e[0m'       # Text Reset
BWhite=$'\e[1;37m'      # Bold White
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems in your `echo` command.

I expanded the variables for brevity.

```
$ echo -e "test TEST test" | sed -e "s/TEST/\e[1;37mTEST\e[0m/g"
test e[1;37mTESTe[0m test
```

First problem: the backslashes are lost somewhere between sed magic and shell magic. You have to escape them.

```
$ echo -e "test TEST test" | sed -e "s/TEST/\\e[1;37mTEST\\e[0m/g"
test e[1;37mTESTe[0m test
```

Still doesn't work. Maybe more escaping?

```
$ echo -e "test TEST test" | sed -e "s/TEST/\\\e[1;37mTEST\\\e[0m/g"
test \e[1;37mTEST\e[0m test
```

Finaly the backslashes are coming through. I have no idea why we need three backslashes, that is some weird sed magic.

Second problem: the `echo -e` is pointless. `-e` enables interpretation of backslash escapes, but all `echo -e` gets to interpret is `"test TEST test"`. The backslash escapes are coming from sed, which does not care about them and prints them raw.

What you want is this:

```
$ echo -e $(echo "test TEST test" | sed -e "s/TEST/\\\e[1;37mTEST\\\e[0m/g")
test TEST test
```

with bold TEST in output.

Here is the full script with the changes:

```
#!/bin/bash

ColorOff='\\\e[0m'       # Text Reset
BWhite='\\\e[1;37m'      # Bold White

string="test TEST test"
echo -e $(echo "$string" | sed -e "s/TEST/${BWhite}TEST${ColorOff}/g")
```

Comment: Btw, `echo -e "${BWhite}AAAA${ColorOff}"` shows `\AAAA\`. It's a pity, because than I need to keep regular_color_constants and SED_color_constants. Actually, I want to have only regular_color_constants, and fix echo and sed options to get what I want.

Comment: That solution is rather fragile (what if `$string` contains a backslash?) and is quite a bit more complicated than necessary. To understand quoting, take things one at a time. E.g. the three backslashes aren't sed magic at all: first there are double quotes, and `"\\\e"` is the two-character string `\e`; then sed understands `\e` as “the character `e` literally”.